OutlinedTextfield start a call
I need some help with Android development. We have an application (using Jetpack), which has an input field that is an OutlinedTextField. The client has requested that if a valid phone number is entered into this field, it should appear as a link (similar to HTML) so that it can be selected and a call can be initiated. How can this be implemented?
I tried some code with annotatedString, but didnt work well...
Edit:
So much new information has come in. The client is also open to having a call button pop up when selecting text (Android can do this, but unfortunately I don't even know the exact name of it or how it works).
Now I use this solution: Jetpack Compose Text hyperlink some section of the text
What they would really like, however, is for a blue, underlined link to appear in the OutlinedTextField that, when clicked, would initiate a call...

Please [edit] the question and provide the code you have so far. Also please clarify if there can be other text beside the phone number, or if it would suffice if the entire TextField is clickable.

Your approach on having an annotated string can work
But Comming to your question on how to have a custom action when selecting text is by making use of the ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT
You can make your custom activity capable of handling the text selection by adding a Manifest filter like so
<activity
    android:name=".ProcessTextActivity"
    android:label="@string/process_text_action_name">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>

Then you can obtain the selected text like so in the onCreate of your activity made above
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.process_text_main);
  CharSequence text = getIntent()
      .getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT);
  // process the text
}


This can be a good place to start with
Read more about this here
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999

I tried to implement it, but it didn't really work out. Only the basic menu is accessible. I added it to the manifest and created a ComponentActivity for it. It would be so much easier if the menu that the Android OS uses by default was simply available. I also don't understand why I only see the four basic functions (copy, select all, delete, etc.) in the app, when in any other app I can access the device's default menu, which would handle phone numbers in my case as well.

If it's a valid phone number, the phone app on the device should pick it up ideally
